# Target class [Frontend\PagesController] does not exist

Tags: php, html

I know another way to declare 'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\PagesController@blog' like that but what is the wrong when I use 'Frontend\PagesController@blog'?
Note: I am using Laravel 8.

**This is route:**

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/blog', 'Frontend\PagesController@blog')->name('blog.page');
```

**This is controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
   public function blog(){
      return view('frontend.pages.blog');
       }
 }
```

Comment: in laravel 8 we should use the route as Route::get(
    '/blog',
    [App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\PagesController, 'blog']
)->name('blog.page');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the namespace for the controllers either in the `RouteServiceProvider.php` or in `web.php`.

In `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

In `routes/web.php`

```
use App\Http\Controllers;
```